# New to Bayesian statistics, getting confused with the definitions and sub-understanding of how it works

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm sorry if these seem like rudimentary questions, but I'm self taught trying to grasp an understanding that seems a but beyond me right now. Here's my situation.

A meteorologist is interested in predicting temperature extremes for a location in the southern United States. From daily temperature records for this location she extracts the annual maximum temperature over a 10 year period. The mean of the observations is $98.2~.$ She assumes that each observation is independently distributed as $N(\mu, 3^2).$ A historical study suggests that $\mu \sim N(90, 102).$

This was the scenario I was given, I was then asked to derive the $95\%$ posterior Highest Density Interval for $\mu$ with posterior $N(98.1,0.94^2)$ which I managed to do.

What I am confused about is this :
The meteorologist says: “There is a probability of $0.95$ that $\mu$ lies between $a$ and $b.$”
Is her claim correct? I assume not because of the differences of historical data which may skew the results.

I also have no clue how to describe why a Bayesian analysis mught be preferable to a frequentist analysis of these annual temperature data.

Answer (score 3):

If $\mu$ describes a real-world quantity (say the mean temperature on May 26 in a particular location), it either lies in a given interval $(a,b)$ or it doesn't.  There is no probability involved, so a statement like "there is a probability of $0.95$ that $\mu$ is between $85$ and $95$" is meaningless.  What statistics lets you do is something subtly different. You use a certain procedure that takes a set of data and returns an interval $[a,b]$.  If the data are a sample from a distribution in a certain class, the probability that the resulting interval will contain $\mu$ is $0.95$.

Comment: The first part makes perfect sense, don't know how I didn't realize earlier. For the second part, I'm more asking why a Bayesian analysis would be used instead of a frequentist analysis?